# .getBorder() not showing borders set from other cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Example: If I set a right border in cell D2, then look at `.getBorder().getLeft().getBorderStyle()` in D3, there is no border, yet when I clear borders from cell D3, it clears the border that was set in D2, which tells me that it sees that there is a border there in some capacity.

If I set a border in D2, is there a way via GAS to tell if that border is there in D3?

edit:  I am trying to tell if there is a border between two cells, regardless of what cell the border was set in.  I.E., I set a right border in D2 and I want to see it programmatically from cell D3.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, I think that when the cell "D2" has the border at the right and the border of cell "D3" is removed by `sheet.getRange("D3").setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false)`, the left border of the cell "D2" is not removed while the bottom border of the cell "D2" is removed. If my understanding is not correct, please tell me.

Comment: If you think that this is a bug then you should report it through the issue tracker -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#bugs